# Manipulating XML element to get value from Sub-element in Erlang

Tags: xml, erlang, ejabberd

I have this in `Packet`:

```
{xmlelement,"message",
  [{"from", "ddfadfdf.com@54.69.16.10/26526129921433241378891365"},
   {"to", "afdafdfaf.com@54.69.16.10/30014432481433242528199830"}],
    [{xmlelement,"received",
       [{"xmlns",
        "urn:xmpp:receipts"},
        {"id", "018A12FB-0718-4304-87FD-430C59EDB4F9"}],
   []}]}
```

I just need to get the value of the `id` attribute under the `received` XML element.

Comment: It seems that this questions is for ejabberd 2.1.x. Please, note that recent ejabberd versions use #xmlel{} records data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use function `xml:get_path_s`, asking it to descend into the element called `received` to get the attribute called `id`:

```
> xml:get_path_s(Packet, [{elem, "received"}, {attr, "id"}]).
"018A12FB-0718-4304-87FD-430C59EDB4F9"
```

---

Note that the question and above solution are for older versions of ejabberd, namely 2.1.x.  You can tell the difference because older versions use `xmlelement` records as in the question, but newer versions use `xmlel` records instead.

For newer ejabberd versions, the `xml` module has been replaced by [`fxml`](https://github.com/processone/fast_xml/blob/master/src/fxml.erl). The function names are the same, just change the module name:

```
fxml:get_path_s(Packet, [{elem, "received"}, {attr, "id"}]).
```

Comment: Hi @legoscia I'm sorry if this sounds naive but i am new to ejabberd and erlang. While testing this out in ejabberdctl live the error thrown is that this function or get_tag_attr_s are undefined.. Any way i can include them ?

Comment: As noted in the comment on the question, this answer applies to an older version of ejabberd. Newer ejabberd versions use the `fxml` module. Here is [the source code of `fxml:get_path_s`](https://github.com/processone/fast_xml/blob/master/src/fxml.erl#L345-L363). It looks like the calling convention is the same as for `xml:get_path_s`.